# Column filtering DataTable, remove specific column filter

Tags: javascript, datatables

I'm using the Column filter from the DataTables library, it adds a filter for each column in my table, the problem and that I need to remove the filter from the first column because it is a checkbox. I have tried some things without success, I will leave the codes that I am using.

Link DataTables: https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedheader/examples/options/columnFiltering.html

My Table:

```
<table id="table" class="table table-sm table-responsive display text-center" style="width:100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th><input type="checkbox" id="selectAll" /></th>
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>Filial</th>
                    <th>Serie</th>
                    <th>Documento</th>
                    <th>Nop</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
           
        </table>
```

JS:

```
     $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#selectAll").click(function () {
        let select = $(this).is(":checked")
        $("[type=checkbox]").prop('checked', select)
    })
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#table thead tr').clone(true).appendTo('#table thead');
    $('#table thead tr:eq(0) th').each(function (i) {
            $(this).html('<input type="text" />');

            $('input', this).on('keyup change', function () {
                if (table.column(i).search() !== this.value) {
                    table
                        .column(i)
                        .search(this.value)
                        .draw();
                }
            });         
    });
```

Comment: [how-to-disable-filtering-on-specific-columns](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/58468/how-to-disable-filtering-on-specific-columns)

Comment: Hello, I need to remove the search input from the first column, this link shows how to disable the search in a column without removing the filter

Comment: To avoid drawing the `<input>` control in the first place, look at this line: `$('#table thead tr:eq(0) th').each( function (i) {`. Here, `i` represents a loop counter. When the counter is `0`, you are building the input control for column index `0` (the first column). You can therefore use an `if(i > 0) { ... }` statement inside that function to ignore the first iteration of the loop.

Comment: this worked to remove the input from the first column, but it removed the checkbox that I put in the first th, I uploaded an image of the before and after, I need to keep this checkbox from the first th to select all the fields

Comment: Prints: Before: https://ibb.co/Gt9NnFc  After:  https://ibb.co/f8S0GNq

Comment: You can [edit] your question to show your updated approach (show us the code!) and explain there what is happening. Otherwise, we don't really know what changes you made.

Comment: my only modification was the one you posted by inserting the if (i> 0), this removed the input from the first column, however it removed the checkbox to select all.

Comment: OK - understood - but I don't know how exactly you made your changes. When I make my suggested changes to my test version of your code, that does not happen. Instead, I see the original checkbox which was cloned from the original HTML table (which you can remove easily enough). In other words, So, without seeing your code, I do not know why your end result is different from mine. I don't want to post an answer, since I don't know if it will actually help you, at this point.

Comment: I understand, I made the modification of my question with the updated code and at the end a print before and after, I hope I can explain my problem and thank you for your help.

Comment: Thank you for the update - and, yes, that code change is what I was expecting (as you already knew!). I do not know why the checkbox is disappearing for you. I cannot recreate that behavior. I do see that you are using `id="table"` in your HTML, but you are using `id="tabelaOperador"` in your jQuery. I assume that is only a copy/paste issue - and not actually in the code you are executing.

Comment: Yes I am Brazilian, I forgot to translate in JS when I copied it, edited it correctly, for me it doesn't work, I will continue debugging the code and thank you very much for your attention

Comment: @andrewjames i found out it was a problem in my css, please add your solution as an answer so you can add it as a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid drawing the  control in the first place, take a look at this line:

```
$('#table thead tr:eq(0) th').each( function (i) {
```

Here, `i` represents a loop counter. When the counter is 0, you are building the input control for column index 0 (the first column). You can therefore use an `if(i > 0) { ... }` statement inside that function to ignore the first iteration of the loop.

Because you are cloning a heading row which already contains a checkbox in the first column, you may also need to remove the "cloned" checkbox using `$( this ).empty();`.

```js
$('#table thead tr:eq(0) th').each(function(i) {

  if (i == 0) {
    $( this ).empty();
  } else {
    var title = $(this).text();

    $(this).html('<input type="text" />');

    $('input', this).on('keyup change', function() {
      if (table.column(i).search() !== this.value) {
        table
          .column(i)
          .search(this.value)
          .draw();
      }
    });
  }

});
```